# Effect of pressure on the reaction rate of a reaction that produces a gas

Tags: thermodynamics

If an irreversible reaction that produces a gas from say a solid and a liquid is in a closed system. How would the reaction rate be effected by increasing the pressure in the container?

I'm guessing that it would slow the rate of the reaction as the added gas from the reaction would further increase the pressure and that seems like it would be unfavorable. However the answer key says that the reaction rate would not be effected as there is no gas in the reactants which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rate of reaction will be unaffected as it is related to kinetics it will change with temperature and other factors.You can read more about that here.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_rate)

now i think in your question equilibrium is already attained and they are asking if **rate** of forward/backward reaction is changed or not.
so that would not change as it **depends on temperature and catalyst**.
note:catalyst can increase decrease rate of forward/backward reaction to equal extent hence overall equilibrium constant is still not affected.

now it is true that something is changed when pressure is increased.as you said that when pressure is increased the partial pressure of gaseous product will increase.

this would make **(reaction quotient)>(equilibrium constant)**.

hence the reaction will then go in backward direction to re-attain equilibrium.

In case of an irreversible reaction which is going forward the rate of reaction depends only on reactants,why?

Refer this text[image]
from the link i shared earlier

As you said it is a strictly forward reaction the products have to do nothing with the reaction as they are formed and simply remain like that.
(Note: if the reaction could go backward then it would have also depended on the products as they would have started to act like reactants for backward path)

So now the reaction rate depends only on the original reactants which are solid and aqueous form and clearly both of them are not affected by any change in pressure.

you can also see the following text for additional info.
(https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Bellarmine_University/BU%3A_Chem_104_(Christianson)/Phase_2%3A_Understanding_Chemical_Reactions/4%3A_Kinetics%3A_How_Fast_Reactions_Go/4.1%3A_The_Speed_of_Reactions)

Comment: Okay thank you, that makes sense to me, however in this case the reaction was not an equilibrium reaction it is strictly a forward reaction. This was the given reaction. Fe(s) + 2HCl(aq) -> H2(g) + FeCl2(aq)

Comment: please mention the whole data of question from next time

Comment: I have edited my answer, check it if that is what you wanted to ask.Also mention your research from next time while asking a question.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I have done too many equilibrium problems and am overthinking this. But what you said makes sense.